# Spring boot job scheduler start and stop

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I am new to spring boot scheduler. I want to schedule multiple jobs to start and stop based on user requirements. The start and stop have to be exposed as a restful service. Is there a way to achieve this using a spring scheduler where I can start a job when the user requests it and stop it when a stop is requested?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to trigger method as new thread annotate with @Async.
If need trigger job based on user trigger and stop based on user trigger spring batch good option if its allowed
running spring batch job

```
 jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameter);
```

stop running job.

```
  jobexplorer.stop(jobExecution.getId);
```